# Is it possible to auto-correct spelling "on space" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, spell-checking, flyspell

I wish there were a way so that when I mistype a word, flyspell could autocorrect it to the "most likely" correction. When I mistype a word and then hit OPTION-TAB to correct it, flyspell ALMOST ALWAYS picks the correct correction by default as the main suggestion.

However, I want flyspell to do this with every word I mistype, WITHOUT my having to hit OPTION-TAB. Just from hitting the SPACE bar and moving on to the next word.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is this "off-topic" or cause for a down-vote? Emacs *is* a development tool, and developers *do* write text/documentation (Ever try to write LaTeX in Word? No thanks!) .. the problem has been explained and there is an objective answer.

Comment: Developers also make coffee, but that doesn't make questions about coffee machines on-topic for SO. The question belongs on http://superuser.com as it's not programming-specific.

Comment: @PaulR And I thought I was strict and happy with the down-arrow :-/

Comment: Well we get 100s of off-topic questions per day on SO - unless we're fairly aggressive about closing or migrating them then the signal-to-noise ratio drops and SO becomes less useful.

Comment: @peter-salazar what command is OPTION-TAB bound to? (You can find this by typing `C-h k Option-Tab`)